# Passing an array via POST in PHP to be inserted into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a form that allows users to input classes and activities into multiple fields, these fields are declared like this :

```
    label for ="classact">Classes and Activities</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "classact[0]" value ="" id ="classact[0]">
        <input type = "text" name = "classact[1]" value ="" id ="classact[1]">
        <input type = "text" name = "classact[2]" value ="" id ="classact[2]">
```

When the form is passed this is the code that handles in the insert:

```
    $maininsert = "INSERT INTO `camptest`
        (`name`, `city`, `phone`, `photo`)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[phone]', '$photoinfo')
        SET @lid = LAST_INSERT_ID()
        ";

    $classactinsert = "INSERT INTO `class_act`
                (`cid`";

    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    {
       if(isset($_POST['classact'][$i]))
       {
          $temp = $i+1; 
          $classactinsert = $classactinsert . ",`act$temp`";
       }
    }

   $classactinsert = $classactinsert . ")
                                VALUES
                                ('@lid'";

   for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
   {
      if(isset($_POST['classact'][$i]))
      {
         $classactinsert = $classactinsert . ",'$_POST[classact][$i]";
      }
   }

  $classactinsert = $classactinsert . ")";                                  

  $indata = $maininsert . $classactinsert;

  $result = mysql_query($indata);
```

I realize thats alot of code, but upon filling out the form and submitting this is the query that gets generated:

```
    INSERT INTO `camptest` (`name`, `city`, `phone`, `photo`) VALUES ('Multiple Activities', 'Nowhere', '555-555-1111', 'images/51127f6b06d1e.jpg') SET @lid = LAST_INSERT_ID() INSERT INTO `class_act` (`cid`,`act1`,`act2`,`act3`) VALUES ('@lid','Array[0],'Array[1],'Array[2])
```

The query is not inserting, but its not throwing back any errors either, even though I have them turned on.

My main question is, what am I doing wrong that is causing the values to act1, act2, and act3 to show up as Array[0], Array[1], and Array[2]?

My secondary question is, am I even going about this the right way? I'm a little new to php and I'm afraid I might be doing this the hard way?

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Your code could be vulnerable to sql injection. Try to use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) api.

Comment: Simply switching to mysqli won't prevent SQL injection; in fact, it could make the vulnerability worse, since `mysql_query` won't allow multiple statements in one SQL query (whereas mysqli can).  You'll want to switch anyway, as the old mysql stuff is deprecated...but for security's sake, you'll also want to learn to use prepared statements, which do quite a bit to prevent SQL injection when used correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not insert anything, because (among other things) your query string is not being built correctly.

```
('@lid','Array[0],'Array[1],'Array[2])
```

The apostrophes are messed up. I'd like to suggest a (in my opinion) cleaner and more structured way to perform your task:

**Note: You are obviously working with the mysql_*-stack, so my example is also based on it. But be aware that this is deprecated. Please use mysqli or even better: [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.**

```
<?php

$maininsert = "INSERT INTO `camptest`
              (`name`, `city`, `phone`, `photo`)
              VALUES
              ('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['city']}', '{$_POST['phone']}', '$photoinfo')";

//perform the main insert and fetch the insert id
mysql_query($maininsert);

$last_id = mysql_insert_id();

// Put the keys and values of the acts in arrays. We can already 
// populate them with the one key-value-pair we already know
$act_keys = array('cid');
$act_values = array($last_id);

foreach($_POST['classact'] as $key => $value) {
  //walk through the POSTed acts and add them to the corresponding array
  $act_keys[] = 'act'.($key+1);
  $act_values[] = $value;
}

//Now build the whole string:
$insert_acts = "INSERT INTO `class_act` 
               (`" . implode("`, `", $act_keys) . "`) 
               VALUES 
               ('" . implode("', '", $act_values) . "')";

//and finally perform the query:
mysql_query($insert_acts);
```

Please also note that this code is highly vulnerable concerning [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and should *absolutely not be used in production*!!! Make sure to either use prepared statements (like with PDO) or/and to sanitize your input properly.

Also, this solution is just my suggestion and one of many ways to do it. But hey, you asked for an opinion :) PHP is *very* flexible language, so it's easy to get stuff done, but there are many ways to get it done, so there are always chances to pick a hard an ugly one. Other, especially strong typed languages might prevent that by design. But PHP is really easy to learn and I'm sure your code will improve gradually :)

Another thing I've noticed: You don't need to specify the array-keys in your HTML, you just need to make clear that it's an array with `[]` behind the name. Also, I'm not sure if the `id`-attributes you using are valid, but you might want use something more simple:

```
<input type="text" name="classact[]" value="" id="classact1">
<input type="text" name="classact[]" value="" id="classact2">
<input type="text" name="classact[]" value="" id="classact3">
```

In the next step, you might want to refactor your code a little to make it even more structured and readable. Since you are performing one task, which is 'inserting something into a table', twice, we could also make a resusable function out of it:

```
<?php 

function my_insert($table, $data) {
  // We leverage the flexibility of associative arrays
  $keys   = "`" . implode("`, `", array_keys($data)) . "`";
  $values = "'" . implode("', '", $data) . "'";

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `{$table}` ({$keys}) VALUES ({$values})");

  return mysql_insert_id(); //This might come in handy...
}

//in order to use this function, we now put our data into associative arrays:
$class_insert = array(
  'name'  => $_POST['name'],
  'city'  => $_POST['city'],
  'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
  'photo' => $photoinfo
);

$class_insert_id = my_insert('camptest', $class_insert); //and pass it to the function

// You can either build the array while looping through the POSTed values like above, 
// or you can pass them in directly, if you know that there will always be 3 values:
$activities_insert = array(
  'cid'  => $class_insert_id,
  'act1' => $_POST['classact'][0],
  'act2' => $_POST['classact'][1],
  'act3' => $_POST['classact'][2]
); 

$activities_insert_id = my_insert('class_act', $activities_insert);
```

There sure is enough room for improvement and optimization - just wanted to show you how awesome PHP can be :-P

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to read over this and give me pointers. Is there anything I need to do to be able to use mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @SmashCode Nope, you don't need anything, PHP has all the good stuff built in. You just use different methods to communicate with the database. I think here's a good starting point: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

Comment: ok, thanks again, I really appreciate the help. I'm sure you can tell I'm pretty new to php.

Comment: @SmashCode You're welcome! We all were new at something when we started learning it. And yes, to be honest, your code doesn't really look too attractive, but that's how it goes - you have to start somewhere in order to get better :) My code probably didn't look any better when I started with PHP. You obviously did put some effort into it instead of copy/pasting it from somewhere; and you asked for feedback and not for a solution - I like that! :-D

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles across this question, I chose this as the answer because the PDO stuff led me to where I needed to be. If you are doing it this way, you should really reconsider, and then you won't have problems like I had.