# Upload multiple forms to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Alright I am trying to upload images and then an image description. The image is uploaded to the database but the text fields are not.

I thought my code was correct but for some reason nothing is going to the database. I think nothing is getting stored into the array and I'm not sure why.

Here is my form.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php">
<div id="filediv">
<div id="imagefiles">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<label>Upload File:
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" id="userfile" multiple></label>
<label>Item Name: <input name='itemname[]' type="text"></label>
<label>Item Description: <input name="itemdesc[]" type="text"></label>
<label>Item Timeframe: <input name='itemtime[]' type="text"></label>
<label>Item Donor: <input name='itemdonor[]' type="text"></label>
<label>Hidden Information: <input name='hidden[]' type="text"></label>
 </div>
 </div>
<br>

<input type="button" id ="thebutton" value="Add Another File" />
<input name="UploadFile" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is my function

```
function uploadFile()
{
include 'functions.php';
hasSession();
session_start();
$dbhost =   '';
$dblogin = '';
$dbpass = '!';
$dbbase = '';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dblogin, $dbpass, $dbbase);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
    exit; 
} 
$arrCount = count($_POST["itemname"]);

$name[] = $_POST["itemname"];
$donor[] = $_POST["itemdonor"];
$desc[] = $_POST["itemdesc"];
$time[] = $_POST["itemtime"];
$hide[] = $_POST["hidden"];

for($i=0; $i<$arrCount; $i++){
    $sql = "INSERT into items (name, donor, time, desc, hidden) VALUES ('$name[$i]', '$donor[$i]', '$desc[$i]', '$time[$i]', $hide[$i]')";
}
$numFiles = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
for($x=0;$x<$numFiles;$x++){
//($_FILES['userfile'][$counter]['error'] == 0) && 
    if (($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$x] > 0)){
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$x];
        $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$x];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$x];
        $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$x];
            if ((($_FILES['userfile']['type'][$x] == "image/gif")   
            || ($_FILES['userfile']['type'][$x]== "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES['userfile']['type'][$x] == "image/png")
            || ($_FILES['userfile']['type'][$x] == "image/pjpeg")))
            {
                $fp=fopen($tmpName,'r');
                $content=fread($fp,filesize($tmpName));
                $SourceImage=imagecreatefromstring($content);
                $SourceWidth=imagesx($SourceImage); 
                $SourceHeight=imagesy($SourceImage);
                $ratio=$SourceWidth/$SourceHeight;
                $DestWidth=100;
                $DestHeight=$DestWidth/$ratio;
                $DestinationImage=imagecreatetruecolor($DestWidth,$DestHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($DestinationImage,$SourceImage,0,0,0,0,$DestWidth,$DestHeight,$SourceWidth,$SourceHeight); 
                ob_start(); 
                imagejpeg($DestinationImage); 
                $BinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents(); 
                ob_end_clean(); 
                $thumb = addslashes($BinaryThumbnail);
                $content=addslashes($content);
                fclose($fp);
                $fileName = addslashes($fileName);  
                mysql_connect('hartslogmuseum.db.11661984.hostedresource.com','hartslogmuseum','Alexandria1!');
                mysql_select_db('hartslogmuseum');
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (name,size,type,content,thumbnail) VALUES ('$fileName','$fileSize','$fileType','$content','$thumb')") or die('Error, query failed');
           }else{
                $fp=fopen($tmpName,'r');
                $content=fread($fp,filesize($tmpName));
                $content=addslashes($content);
                fclose($fp);
                $fileName = addslashes($fileName);  
                $link = mysqli_connect('!');
                mysqli_select_db($link,'');
                mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO images (name,size,type,content) VALUES ('$fileName','$fileSize', '$fileType','$content')"); 
          }
    }else{
        echo "Error: ". $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$x]."<br/>";
    }
}
    echo "<script>alert('The file(s) has been uploaded');location.replace('uploaded.php');</script>";
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that executes your query?

Comment: I might be completely off my rocker but shouldn't you be calling your values like this `$name[0][$i]` since you are assigning them like this `$name[] = $_POST["itemname"];`. If you want to leave your SQL unchanged then can you try assigning the variables like this `$name = $_POST["itemname"];`? [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/scz-i1p)

Comment: I agree with MonkeyZeus, however you should probably change your input name settings. ` $desc[] ` should really just be `$desc`. Otherwise this variable will resolve to an array of length one where the value of that one pair is an array of values of itemdesc.

Comment: Yes the user can add the form as many times as they want and it reappears on the screen. So there would be repeating form inputs.
'$arrCount = count($_POST["itemname"]);

$name = $_POST["itemname"];
$donor = $_POST["itemdonor"];
$descr = $_POST["itemdesc"];
$time = $_POST["itemtime"];
$hide = $_POST["hidden"];

for($i=0; $i<$arrCount; $i++){
 $sql = "INSERT into bookhjr10_items ('name', 'donor', 'time', 'descr', 'hidden') VALUES ('$name[$i]', '$donor[$i]', '$descr[$i]', '$time[$i]', $hide[$i]')";
}'

Comment: Have a look at this answer on SO, it may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/a/14735483/1415724 - I Google'd "insert into mysqli php input array brackets" and found that answer. It's hard for me to say exactly where the problem is with your text inputs. @Pureblood

Comment: I noticed something. You have a missing apostrophe/quote in `'$time[$i]', $hide[$i]'` change that to `'$time[$i]', '$hide[$i]'` that may be the problem and it won't insert anything because of that. See my **EDIT** @Pureblood

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a reserved word and needs to be wrapped in backticks.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Such as:

```
`desc`
```

---

```
$sql = "INSERT into items (name, donor, time, `desc`, hidden) VALUES ('$name[$i]', '$donor[$i]', '$desc[$i]', '$time[$i]', $hide[$i]')";
```

As `MonkeyZeus` stated and was about to write the same comment (at that very same time), it's best to wrap table names and columns with backticks.

For example:

```
$sql = "INSERT into `items` (`name`, `donor`, `time`, `desc`, `hidden`) VALUES ('$name[$i]', '$donor[$i]', '$desc[$i]', '$time[$i]', $hide[$i]')";
```

---

### EDIT:

I noticed there is a missing quote for

```
  '$time[$i]', $hide[$i]'
```

- - - - - - - - - - - - - ^

Change to:

```
'$time[$i]', '$hide[$i]'
```

Full line of code:

```
$sql = "INSERT into `items` (`name`, `donor`, `time`, `desc`, `hidden`) VALUES ('$name[$i]', '$donor[$i]', '$desc[$i]', '$time[$i]', '$hide[$i]')";
```

Comment: I usually recommend encasing ALL fields and table names in backticks when using MySQL

Comment: Yes I agree. I was just going to write that just as you wrote your comment. @MonkeyZeus

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that error but the date is still not getting to the datebase. I edited my original post to show full function. The image function is working fine and the file is getting uploaded. It is just that the text fields of the form are not getting through

Comment: The +1 was from me btw =) but please check out my comment on the OP

Comment: You're welcome. Why are you using brackets for your POST values. Are there more than one entry per post/per input being inserted in your DB? @Pureblood

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus I noticed your comment above. I asked the OP about that too just now. Wondering why.

Comment: Another thing, you might want to check to see what field type you have your `date` set as. @Pureblood

Comment: I also noticed you're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions. Use all `MySQLi_` @Pureblood another possible reason for errors.

Comment: I think `$arrCount = count($_POST["itemname"]);` definitely suggests the possibility of multiple items. Good catch on the `mysql_` and `mysqli_`!

Comment: Also consider what [MonkeyZeus said in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252726/upload-multiple-forms-to-database#comment30209391_20252726) above. @Pureblood and the PHPfiddle http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/scz-i1p he made.

Comment: Spotted another error/factor. Missing quote in `, $hide[$i]'` @MonkeyZeus - May (hope) very well be the culprit.

Comment: Haha I've honestly given up. There are too many things fundamentally wrong with this that I'll bet OP is gonna post another question after they fix these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change  desc column because desc is a reserved mysql word for order, an application of it would be:

```
    SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC
```

thus you cannot use desc as a column name. To get info about such errors, its good to use the

```
    mysql_error()
```

function after every query i.e

```
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())
```

So change that column name from *desc* to another name that's not a mysql reserved word.
Good luck!